# Can JaVers be integrated with Hibernate?

Tags: javers

I've seen you can use JaVers to serialize changes to a database, but I can't find a good example about Spring or Hibernate integration. I would also know if I can change the generated table names and columns.

Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javers doc, there is the example you are looking for: 
http://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/#spring-jpa-example

If you are using Spring Boot, examples for `JaVers Spring Boot starter for SQL`
http://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/

We recommend using the second option - JaVers Spring Boot starter

Comment: I've seen the sample code, but I'm not sure about which libraries should be included in pom.xml

Comment: you mean javers libraries dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Code is useful, but not always is complete.

Comment: could you tell me what is missing in this doc http://javers.org/documentation/spring-boot-integration/? Did you go through get-javers-starters section?

Comment: I wanted just Spring no Spring Boot :)